# Allowing only one cell in a row to have value

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I am working with cells `A1` through `C1` in Excel, which each represents three separate options, where a user should enter either 1 or 0. The value 1 accepts the option whereas 0 rejects the option. Now, if I wish to only allow for one of these options to be chosen at a time; is it possible to delete any values that have been previously entered?

For example:

If the user first chooses the option in cell `A1`, then it will look like this:

`A1=1 B1=0 C1=0`

If the user then decides to switch to the option in cell `B1`, without first manually deleting the value in `A1`, it will look like this:

`A1=1 B1=1 C1=0`

Is there a way to automatically delete the previously chosen option so that once the user switches from the option in `A1`, into, for example, `B1` it looks like this:

`A1=0 B1=1 C1=0`

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2 rows or more

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    r = Target.Row
    If Target.Value = 1 Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Range("A" & r & ":C" & r).Value = 0
      Target = 1
      Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row <> 1 Or Target.Column > 3 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = 1 Then
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Range("A1:C1").Value = 0
  Target = 1
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Is it also possible to apply the code to more rows while not affecting the option in row 1? E.g. if I have another set of three options in A2 through C2 and I want the option chosen in this range to be independent of whatever is chosen is A1 through C1?